# characterisation of normal quasi-projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to show the following: "Let $X$ be a quasi-projective curve. We claim that $X$ is normal if and only if every finite surjective morphism $f_Y : Y \rightarrow X$ that is an isomorphism over an open subset is actually an isomorphism."

The reverse implication is direct since the normalisation $\nu : X^{\nu} \rightarrow X$ is a birational finite surjective morphism so by assumption $\nu$ is an isomorphism and then $X$ is isomorphic to $X^{\nu}$ so it is normal.

I have more troubles with the direct implication. Here is what I was thinking about but I don't succeed to conclude: assume that $X$ is a normal quasi-projective curve and let $f: Y \rightarrow X$ be a morphism which is an isomorphism over an open subset. We want to show that it is actually an isomorphism over $Y$. We only have to prove the injectivity, and for this, it is enough to show that the induced homomorphism $f^{*} : \mathbb{K}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{K}[Y]$ is surjective. Since $f$ is finite over $X$, there exists an open covering of $X$ by affine varieties, say $X = \bigcup_i U_i$, such that for any of these $U_i$, $f^{-1}(U_i) = V_i$ is isomorphic to an affine variety and $f^* \mathcal{A}_{U_i} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}_{V_i}$ makes $\mathcal{A}_{V_i}$ into a finitely generated $\mathcal{A}_{U_i}$-module. In particular $\mathcal{A}_{V_i}$ is integral over $\mathcal{A}_{U_i}$ which is integrally closed since $X$ is normal (so $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ is integrally closed for any $P \in X$ then so is $\bigcap_{P \in U_i} \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$). Thus $\mathcal{A}_{U_i} \cong \mathcal{A}_{V_i}$ for all $i$. From this how can I obtain an isomorphism on the whole coordinate ring? I was thinking to use the fact that the localization "preserves" surjectivity but then I am never using the fact that $X$ is a curve... What's wrong with this reasoning? Any kind of hint is welcome, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The reason you are not using curves is because it is not necessary. An irreducible (quasi-projective) variety $X$ is normal if and only if for any finite morphism $f:Y\to X$, where $Y$ is irreducible and an isomorphism on a non-empty open subset of $X$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I still have some doubts concerning the conclusion, is the fact that $\mathcal{A}_{U_i} \cong \mathcal{A}_{V_{i}}$ really enough for obtaining the surjectivity of $\mathbb{K}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{K}[Y]$? I still think I am missing an important argument...

Comment: I do not know what you mean by $K[X], K[Y]$. Are these ring of regular functions on $X,Y$? If $X, Y$ are projective, these are just the base fields, so the surjectivity will not be very useful.

Comment: Yes it is the ring of regular function on $X$ and $Y$, that are here, quasi-projective.

Comment: @Mohan I have tried to work again on the question but I am still confused, also by your answer : what do you mean by "surjectivity will not be very useful" ? I am just using the fact that if the induced ring homomorphism is surjective then the morphism of varieties is injective. I think it works for quasi-projective varieties and not only for affine ones. This result seems to be classical, is there a more elegant way of proving it? (assuming that my proof works which is not really certain)

Comment: You are better off working on affine open sets, since for ANY projective varieties (say over an algebraically closed field) $X,Y$, and a morphism $f:Y\to X$, you have $k[X]\to k[Y]$ an isomorphism, since both are just $k$. Tells you nothing about about $f$. If $f$ is a finite morphism between affine varieties, then $k[Y]$ is a finite module over $k[X]$ and if for all primes, localizing at them makes it an isomorphism (by your assumption that it is an isomorphism on a non-empty open set and $X$ is normal), then $k[X]\to k[Y]$ is an isomorphism, proving what you need.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! I get the first part of your answer but I still have a problem when localizing: say $f$ is an isomorphism over $W \subset Y$ open. For any $w \in W$ we have that $\mathcal{O}_{f(W),f(w)} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{W,w}$. Seen as a $k[X]$-module $\mathcal{O}_{W,w}$ is integral (because $f$ is finite) and $\mathcal{O}_{f(W),f(w)}$ is integrally closed (as $X$ is normal) so $\mathcal{O}_{f(W),f(w)} \cong \mathcal{O}_{W,w}$. What I don't understand is why I can extend it to the whole $Y$? Is it because $W$ is dense in $Y$?

Comment: It definitely doesn't work : all I succeed to show with this method is that $X$ and $Y$ are birational, but affine varieties that are birational are note necessarily isomorphic... Does someone have another idea? I have tried to consider the projective closure of $X$ but again I fail in concluding.

Comment: If $X\to Y$ birational, FINITE and $Y$ normal, then it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for being so quick in your answer! I don't know this result and I have spent several hours looking for a similar property... Can you explain me why it holds or give me a reference please?